# Transaction never finished Neo4j

Tags: spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-transactions

I have a method which should create a sub-graph defined this way:

```
@Transactional
public Post createAndLink(Appuser appuser, Post post, String linkTo) {

    Post savedPost = null;
    if(post != null && appuser != null){
        post.setCreatedBy(appuser);
        if(post.getId() == null && post.getId() == ""){
            post.setId("IND"+GenerateUUID.getUUID());
        }
        System.out.println(">>> Id created : "+post.getId());

        //Date check
        String d = post.getDate();
        if(d != null && d.length() == 11 && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(0, 4))
                && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(5, 7)) && ConversionUtils.isNumeric(d.substring(8, 10))){
            if(!ConversionUtils.isPastDate(d)){
                System.out.println("Cannot save post with date after today");
                return null;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(">>> Date created : "+post.getDate());

        //People check
        Set<People> people = new HashSet<People>();
        if(post.getPeople() != null){
            for(People p : post.getPeople()){
                People pFromDb = peopleService.findById(p.getId());
                people.add(pFromDb != null ? pFromDb : new People("PPL"+GenerateUUID.getUUID(), p.getName()));
            }
            post.setPeople(people);
        }
        System.out.println(">>> People created : "+post.getPeople());

        //Place check
        if(post.getPlace() != null){
            Place pFromDb = placeService.findById(post.getPlace().getId());
            post.setPlace(pFromDb != null ? pFromDb : new Place(post.getPlace().getId()));
        }

        System.out.println(">>> Place created : "+post.getPlace());

        System.out.println("Post checking OK.");

        savedPost = repository.findById(linkTo);

        if(savedPost != null){
            Set<Post> linked = new HashSet<Post>();
            linked.add(savedPost);
            post.setLinkedPosts(linked);
        }
        template.save(post);

        System.out.println("=====> [saveWithUser]: Saved OK!");
    }

    return savedPost;
}
```

When I call this method within a loop, sometimes it gets stuck (in one of the iterations) in the execution of `template.save(post)`.

The same behaviour is observed when I call this method unitarily from a GUI.

PS: The findBy methods are not transactional.

I'm stuck on it since 2 weeks and I can't find a way to solve it :/

Thanks for any feedback.

**Edit 1:**

Logs produced by the method:

```
>>> Id created : IND6f770750-7834-40ae-a07e-fc81bbb3c657
>>> Date created : 2009Y09M20D
>>> People created : [People [id=PPLaf830449-b15c-4c71-b706-abd11492b825, name=Mary], People [id=PPLdf53d2c7-06b1-49c8-9b69-3b765d9b2ee6, name=Laptop]]
>>> Place created : Place [id=2918548, name=null]
Post checking OK.
```

PS: The iteration before the blocked one, it shows a normal log execution but nothing created in the DB

**Edit 2**:

And sometimes I get this error (always during the 2nd iteration while 1st shows normal logs but writes nothing on DB):

```
javax.transaction.RollbackException: Tx status is: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
```

Comment: `it gets stuck` means what ? exception ? (and what's the stacktrace ?) blocked ? (post the logs, with transactional/database logs activated)

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. It means Without any evolution neither exceptions (as if it's still in progress).

Can you tell me where can I find the logs you mentionned and how to to activate the option please?

Comment: Most of the time the logs are available in your IDE's console. If not, they are probably in a file named *something*.log. I don't know how to activate specific logs for transaction since it depends on your logging library. (log4j is widely used and comes with a log4j.properties or log4j.xml to configure it) (for neo4j : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html#_server_logging_configuration)

Comment: Thanks.
I'm going to reproduce with the logs activated and post it here

Comment: I can't get any readable logs. I'm lost :/
All of the logs (except messages.log) are encoded

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of your application when it hangs?

Comment: You should try to create a reproducible unit test and publish it as a project.

Comment: r'you sure this condition should be AND? i believe OR: `if(post.getId() == null && post.getId() == ""){`

Comment: @ulkas: Yes you're right but, actually in my program it's written this way :
if(story.getId() != null && story.getId() != ""){
}else{
story.setId("IND"+GenerateUUID.getUUID());
}

I changed it when I tried to simplify it to be put here

Comment: i'm either unfamiliar with `@Transactional` or these conditions are reverted: test for `== null` and not for `!= null` in the lines: `if(post.getPeople() != null)`, `if(post.getPlace() != null)`, `if(savedPost != null)`.

Comment: @ulkas: It should be !=null as I'm persisting people, place... only when the post object to be saved has already this objects

Comment: @MichaelHunger: I've edited the post to add the logs the method is producing. Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: re the RollbackException: do you by any chance catch an exception from some service in a transaction? spring automatically marks transaction to rollback in that case..

Comment: I tried to debug and I found that it's blocked in invoke method of the PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor class.

Also I deleted any @Transactional or any explicit transactional bloc from the code to be executed and I was waiting for a NotInTransaction Exception but I got exactly the same behaviour described in the main post.
I'm getting crazy :(

Comment: Can you also share your config and all the injection points for both controllers and how they are set up, remember spring only takes care of tx-management when you inject your beans via spring, not when you pass them directly via normal Java-Code.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I got my answer from another thread (by you btw :) ).
Some other Tx in another operation was not closed properly which was causing the endless wait and the Placebo tx.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem (but not yet the solution)

I removed all @Transactional annotations from my service methods (controllers and repositories are not marked as Transactional).

In the method createAndLink described in the main post I added transaction this way :

```
if(post != null && appuser != null){
    Transaction tx = template.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx();
    //I kept the same code...
    //...
    tx.success();
    tx.close();

}
```

Now, when I call this method from a controller A, the tx is of type Placebo. When I call it from a controller B, the tx type is a TopLevel.

I even made a test with calling the controller A method from the controller B (like in the example below) and it worked perfectly (with a TopLevel Tx). When I do the opposite way, the Tx is Placebo.

**Controller A:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newandlinksimilar/{linkedTo}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean createAndLinkNewSimilar(@RequestBody Post post, @PathVariable String linkedTo){
        Post created = null;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (post!= null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            AppuserDetails userDetails = (AppuserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
            Appuser currentUser = appuserService.findByLogin(userDetails.getUsername());
            created = postService.createAndLinkSimilar(currentUser, post, linkedTo);
        }
       return created;
}
```

**Controller B:**

```
@autowired
private ControllerA controllerA;

@RequestMapping("/init")
public ModelAndView init(){
    //I create a new Post object "post" with dummy data
    controllerA.createAndLinkSimilar(post,"XXXXXX");
    //Or postService.createAndLinkSimilar(appuser,post,"XXXXXX");
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Both tests are made from a GUI ajax call to the controller method.

I can't understand when and how Spring choose the type of the transaction?!